# How to create dynamic nested dictionaries in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a list as follows:

```
list_name=["node1","node2","node3",...,"nodeN"]
```

I have a dictionary as follows:

```
dictionary_name:{
  "node1":{
    "node2":true}
   }
}
```

I would like to set node2 to equal the following:

```
 "node2"={"node3":{"node4":{...."nodeN"=true}...}}}
```

I have been unsuccessfully lost in for loops for a while now.

Has anyone got any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you trying to learn about creating nested dictionaries or are you trying to model a chain of nodes in python?

Comment: Probably the latter? ha

Comment: Here is the larger problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65257032/displaying-node-formation-in-dictionary-format-python?noredirect=1#comment115368468_65257032

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
from functools import reduce

list_name=["node1","node2","node3","nodeN"]
print(reduce(lambda k, v: {v: k}, reversed(list_name), True))
```

Output:

```
{'node1': {'node2': {'node3': {'nodeN': True}}}}
```

Comment: Thanks you for your help!

Comment: How would I attach the output to my initial dictionary_name?

Comment: `dictionary_name = reduce(lambda k, v: {v: k}, reversed(list_name), True)`

Answer (score 2):

```
root = d = {'node1': {'node2': True}}
n = 10
keys = ["node{}".format(i) for i in range(1, n+1)]
for k in keys[:-1]:
    # Overwrite the True with a dictionary or create a dictionary,
    # not sure the point of the True values in this problem.
    if k not in d or not isinstance(d[k], dict):
        d[k] = {}
    # Recurse into the nested dictionary
    d = d[k]
# Set the final key to True.
d[keys[-1]] = True
print(root)
```

Comment: Sorry, I am probably being dense, but when I run the above and print d all I get is {'node10': True} without the nesting.

Comment: Yeah sorry I didn't keep a reference to the original dictionary but that should be fixed if you keep a root reference like I added.

Comment: Works! Thanks for your help :)

Comment: A quick query with regards to your solution. Say for example the entries in list_name are random strings instead of "node1", "node2" etc, how would I go about the same problem?

Comment: I moved the keys into a variable.  Should be replaceable with random list.