# Displaying node formation in dictionary format - Python

Tags: python

I am trying to display a set of nodes in a dictionary, So I can more easily see how the nodes are set out.

I have a dictionary:

```
dict1={
   "exmple1":{...},
   "example2"={...}, 
   ...
   "exampleN"={...}}
```

I also have a list of strings

```
list1 = ["str1","str2",..."strN"]
```

I am trying to write a function that looks to see if `dict1["str1"]` exists. If it does exist, I would like it to continue to see if `dict1["str1"]["str2"]` exists and so forth. When `dict["str1"]["str2"]...["strK"]` does not exist I would like

```
dict1["str1"]["str2"]...["strK"]={"strK+1":{"strK+2":...{"strN":True}...}}
```

I have written the following but have become stuck at the #:

```
for x in list1:
    root = dict1
    for i in range(len(x)-1):
            if x[i] in root:
                root = root[x[i]]
            else:
                new_list = x[i:len(x)-1]
                nested_values = reduce(lambda k, v: {v: k}, reversed(new_list), True)
                i = len(x)
                #Add nested_values to the correct location
```

All help is appreciated,

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Stuck at the # means?

Comment: I need to #Add nested_values to the correct location

Comment: Are you sure making a dictionary of nodes is the best way to visualise a set of interconneted nodes? There are some packages for network analysis that could help you  for example [networkx](https://networkx.org/). Could that do what you are after?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. The package looks interesting and I think it could help me in the future, but at the moment, the data comes in string format and I am trying to get it into a node like structure, i.e. in a dictionary.